# Meaning of '@' sign in load fun

Tags: bazel, starlark

I'm trying to find anything about '@' sign in load function in Bazel. We can load things like this

```
load("//foo/bar:file.bzl", library_alias )
```

But also like this

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
```

I couldn't find reason or purpuse of this. Does '@'works as '<>'in include in C/Cpp? I tried looking into Bazel/Starlark repos, but it yield no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to [`load()`](https://bazel.build/concepts/build-files#load) is a label to the build file you want to load from. The `@` is part of the general syntax of labels. It means the label is referring to something from outside the repository in which the label appears.

`//foo/bar:file.bzl` means loading `file.bzl` from the package `foo/bar` in the "current" repository.

`@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl` means load `http.bzl` from the package `tools/build_defs/repo` from the repository `bazel_tools`. (`bazel_tools` is a special repository that is built into bazel itself)

See:

https://bazel.build/concepts/labels

https://bazel.build/external/overview

Comment: Can't belive i missed the labels page. Thanks a lot!